# codeigniter in ubuntu always shows "404 not found"

Tags: codeigniter

welcome page only shows. If I create new controller and view means it shows '404 Not found' .

> Controller - Create.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Create extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('create');
    }
}
```

> View - create.php

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?> 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <body>
       <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have run like this in browser - "http://example.com/Create/". But it shows 404 Not Found. I gave permission to all files also.

Comment: What's your routes for the respective

Comment: http://example.com is site url. Create is controller name

Comment: I mean $route['create'] = "Create/";

Comment: whats your codeigniter version ? are you testing on server or local.?

Comment: version 3.0.0 - and i'm testing in local

Comment: @NarendraSisodia - Sorry I don't get you what you are asking.

Comment: Your code running good with `CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/Create`. Means may be you have any error with config files

Comment: Try error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Hi.. This is working in windows. I'm using "lubuntu" . its may be problem ??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it showing welcome page because default controller is welcome in application\config\routes.php file

`$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`

Only default controller can be use without index.php.

so try this for other controllers `"http://example.com/index.php/controllerName/functionName"`

You can refer to : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I have tried this way ("http://example.com/index.php/controllerName/functionName") also.. but it shows same 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these set?

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page']   = '';
```

Comment: Yes.. But there is no use. Not working in Lubuntu os only. In windows system its working fine.

Comment: @user3387758 I think it is still a capitalization problem. What exactly is the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an upper case issue. Linux is case sensitive.

The fix is that you make sure you capitalize all your `controller` file names i.e in the controller folder, instead of `welcome.php` change it to `Welcome.php`

I hope this helped.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution? cause I desperately need it. I copied the folder from the windows htdocs, which worked perfectly, to the Ubuntu htdocs, which gives the 404 error

Comment: Check the case of your controller. If your script capitalizes then your files should be capitalized too... Let me know exactly what your error is.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable mod_rewrite and set the "AllowOverride" option to "All" in your apache2.conf file.

To enable the mod_rewrite you just need to enter to a terminal and type the folllowing command:

```
a2enmod rewrite (as root user)
```

To set the AllowOverride All in the apache2.conf file you need to open it and set the AllowOverride option from None to All in the  section, like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If it doesn't exist then write it.